# Subset from a list and merge together

Tags: r, list, dplyr, subset

```
my.list <- list()
for(i in 1:2){
  df <- data.frame(year = rep(1980:1981, each = 4), day = rnorm(2*4))
  my.list[[i]] <- df
 }
```

From each element of the list, I want to extract the year and bind together. 
i.e. from `my.list[[1]]` and `my.list[[2]]`, extract the data for 1980 and bind rowise and then from `my.list[[1]]` and `my.list[[2]]`, extract the data for 1981. I could do this:

```
df <- rbindlist(my.list)
df %>% dplyr::filter(year == 1980)
df %>% dplyr::filter(year == 1981)
```

However, I am wondering if there is a direct way to subset from the list instead
of using `rbindlist`

Comment: `rnorm(2*4)` why not `rnorm(8)`?

Comment: what is the sample output?

Comment: For `year==1980` you can use `lapply(my.list, function(x) x[x$year==1980,])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps :

```
purrr::map_df(my.list,~ dplyr::filter(.,year=="1980"))
purrr::map_df(my.list,~ dplyr::filter(.,year=="1981"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bind_rows()` from `dplyr`:

```
my.list %>% 
  bind_rows() %>%
  filter(year == "1980")
```

Or followed by `split`:

```
df <- my.list %>% 
  bind_rows() %>%
  filter(year == "1980")

split(df, df$year)
#
$`1980`
   year        day
1  1980  1.3974267
2  1980  1.7636530
3  1980  0.4856014
4  1980 -0.2657389
9  1980 -0.2607259
10 1980  0.9618104
11 1980  0.8538955
12 1980  0.4187967

$`1981`
   year        day
5  1981  0.1516114
6  1981  1.3766098
7  1981 -0.1803943
8  1981 -1.5676751
13 1981  0.3399565
14 1981  0.5964251
15 1981  1.8714180
16 1981  0.6028704
```

Comment: Thank you but I am avoiding the `bind rows` bit since my list is quite large and hence when it tries to bind, I run out of memory

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question - I devised a little test to see how different functions compare to each other in terms of speed and memory.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rbenchmark)
library(data.table)
```

**DATA**

```
dataList <- function(nobvs = 500, nelements = 2){
  return(lapply(1:nelements, function(k){
    return(data.table(year = rep(1980:1981, each = nobvs), 
                      day = rnorm(2*nobvs)))
  } ))
}
```

**CODE**

*Functions to compare*

```
fnRbindlist <- function(ll = data_list){
  return(rbindlist(l = ll, use.names = T, fill = T)[year == 1980])
}

fnBindRows <- function(ll = data_list){
  return(ll %>% bind_rows() %>% filter(year == 1980))
}

fnPurr <- function(ll = data_list){
  return(purrr::map_df(ll, ~ dplyr::filter(., year == 1980)))
}

fnSubsetRbind <- function(ll = data_list){
  mm <- lapply(ll, function(k) return(k[year == 1980]))
  return(rbindlist(mm, use.names = T, fill = T))
}
```

*Compare Speed*

```
speed_results <- lapply(c(100, 1000, 10000), function(q){
  nobvs <- q
  nelements <- 2
  dat <- benchmark(fnRbindlist(dataList(nobvs, nelements)), 
                   fnBindRows(dataList(nobvs, nelements)),
                   fnPurr(dataList(nobvs, nelements)),
                   fnSubsetRbind(dataList(nobvs, nelements)), 
                   replications = 1000, 
                   order = 'elapsed', 
                   columns = c('test', 'replications', 'elapsed'))
  dat$rank <- 1:nrow(dat)
  dat$nobvs <- nobvs
  dat$nelements <- nelements
  return(dat)
})
```

*Compare memory usage*

```
memory_results <- lapply(c(100, 1000, 10000), function(q){
  nobvs <- q
  nelements <- 2
  dat <- data.table(memRbindlist = pryr::mem_change(fnRbindlist(dataList(nobvs, nelements))), 
                    memBindRows = pryr::mem_change(fnBindRows(dataList(nobvs, nelements))),
                    memPurr = pryr::mem_change(fnPurr(dataList(nobvs, nelements))),
                    memSubsetRbind = pryr::mem_change(fnSubsetRbind(dataList(nobvs, nelements))))
  dat$nobvs <- nobvs
  dat$nelements <- nelements
  return(dat)
})
```

**RESULTS**

```
> rbindlist(l = speed_results, use.names = T, fill = T)[order(test)]
                                         test replications elapsed rank nobvs nelements
 1:    fnBindRows(dataList(nobvs, nelements))         1000    1.75    1   100         2
 2:    fnBindRows(dataList(nobvs, nelements))         1000    2.23    1  1000         2
 3:    fnBindRows(dataList(nobvs, nelements))         1000    6.95    1 10000         2
 4:        fnPurr(dataList(nobvs, nelements))         1000    2.56    3   100         2
 5:        fnPurr(dataList(nobvs, nelements))         1000    3.02    3  1000         2
 6:        fnPurr(dataList(nobvs, nelements))         1000    8.89    4 10000         2
 7:   fnRbindlist(dataList(nobvs, nelements))         1000    2.56    2   100         2
 8:   fnRbindlist(dataList(nobvs, nelements))         1000    2.85    2  1000         2
 9:   fnRbindlist(dataList(nobvs, nelements))         1000    8.17    2 10000         2
10: fnSubsetRbind(dataList(nobvs, nelements))         1000    3.77    4   100         2
11: fnSubsetRbind(dataList(nobvs, nelements))         1000    4.04    4  1000         2
12: fnSubsetRbind(dataList(nobvs, nelements))         1000    8.77    3 10000         2


> rbindlist(l = memory_results, use.names = T, fill = T)
   memRbindlist memBindRows memPurr memSubsetRbind nobvs nelements
1:       -34944       69272   70104         220672   100         2
2:        51312       69272   70104         220672  1000         2
3:        51416       69272   70104         220672 10000         2
```

Based on the above, I'd say `rbindlist` is the best option of the bunch since it is consistently good in speed and has the least memory usage (primary concern in the OP).

Hope this is helpful!